# Table cell width alignments

Tags: html, html-table

I have a `table` set to `width=100%`, with 2 columns.
How do I make the first `table data` to take the `size` of a menu control (inside `td1`), then make `td2` take the `size` of the remaining space.
If I set `td2's` width to `100%`, my menu `collapses/wraps-up`.

Here is my code below:

```
<table border="1" width="100%">
    <tr>
    <td>
    <asp:Menu ID="Menu" runat="server" Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Items>
    <asp:MenuItem Text="Home" Value="Home"></asp:MenuItem>
    <asp:MenuItem Text="ContactUs" Value="ContactUs"></asp:MenuItem>
    <asp:MenuItem Text="About Us" Value="About Us"></asp:MenuItem>
    </Items>
    </asp:Menu>
    </td>
    <td>TD2</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Did you check for earlier answers by searching for ``HTML Table cell width alignments``. There are 36 hits.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4"> Your menu here</div>
  <div class="col-md-8">Content here </div>
</div>
```

You will need bootstrap.

Comment: Hi Nduna, thanks, but when I try this, all it does is put the 2 divs below each other, instead of next to each other